# Unable to connect to server - Atom Nuclide

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I am trying to connect to a remote server using Nuclide in Atom.
I'm getting this message error:

"Unable to connect to server:
The server successfully started, but we were unable to connect.
Original error message:
Version mismatch. Client at 217 while server at 216."
[image: message error image link]

It was working well, but then when I updated the nuclide package in Atom I get that error.

I already updated the nuclide server using npm.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I using the Windows 10 system.

Answer (score 2):

Try `nuclide-start-server` in your server. And check the version in log.

If the version is different in log with your nuclide version, 
Try this.

Remove nuclide.

`npm remove -g nuclide
npm remove nuclide`

Reinstall

`npm install -g npm@latest
npm install -g nuclide`

And check the version again through `nuclide-start-server`.

If there is same error after this, check your npm global package directory using `npm root -g` and see version through `nuclide/package.json`.
It must has same version with your atom nuclide as `"version": "0.218.0"`.

Normally the default directory is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuclide` for npm global packages.